# Wet clothes left up to dry before Shabbos -- does everyone follow the Mishna Brurah that they are muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, washing-clothes

Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchasa says that if wet clothes were left hanging up to dry before the start of shabbos, then they remain muktzeh for all of shabbos, even if they're totally dry the next morning.

He cites the Mishna on Brurah on this, then in the footnotes, notes R' that R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach was rather puzzled by this Mishna Brurah. Wet clothes aren't actually *muktzeh*; if the only shirt you have is sopping wet, you are allowed to put it on and wear it, just try not to squeeze any water out of it. Ergo those clothes on the line were never "unusable."

Does anyone actually rule that such clothes are therefore not *muktzeh*? (Was R' Shlomo Zalman actually disagreeing and saying it would be allowed, or just giving a shrug and saying "but I can't argue with the mishna brurah...)

Comment: I guess I have two questions. A.) Does anyone disagree *l'maysa* with the Mishna Brurah? (Answered below, yes.) B.) When SSK says "RSZA was confused by the Mishna Brurah", did that mean he actually would pasken against it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yalkut Yosef 308:208:

> בגד רטוב שהניחוהו במכונת ייבוש מערב-שבת, מותר להוציאו מהמכונה בשבת אחר
> המכונה תפסיק לפעול, אף שהבגד היה רטוב בבין השמשות. **ומותר להורידו
> מהחבל בשבת.** [ילקוט יוסף שבת כרך ב' עמוד תצ].
>
> If someone placed wet clothing into a dryer before Shabbat, it is
> permissible to remove the clothing from the machine on Shabbat after
> it finishes its cycle and opening the machine will not affect any
> electric process. This is so even if the clothing was still wet during
> *ben hashemashot*. **Likewise, it is permissible to take down laundry from a clothesline.**

He doesn't hold they are *muktza*.

There are related *halachos* in 301b:83 onwards. Interestingly, he *paskens* that one can leave laundry hanging up on Shabbat if it was hung on Friday; it is not *marit ayin*.